# Loop Through String of Words, Return Word With Highest Score According To Character Value in Object - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, increment

I'm trying to figure out how to solve [this kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/57eb8fcdf670e99d9b000272/train/javascript) on CodeWars.

Function `high` recieves a string and returns the word with the highest "score" according to which letters in the word are present. The letters receive a score based on their position in the alphabet. So `a = 1 point, b = 2 points, c = 3 points`, and so on.

I think it makes sense to create an object where all of the letters in the alphabet are assigned a value:

If the letter in the word appears in `alphabetScore`, that word will receive its "points" and continue on to the next letter in the word, increasing the total points of the word.

I have:

```
function high(string) {

  let words = string.split(" ");
  let wordScore = 0;

  const alphabetScore = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
    e: 5,
    f: 6,
    g: 7,
    h: 8,
    i: 9,
    j: 10,
    k: 11,
    l: 12,
    m: 13,
    n: 14,
    o: 15,
    p: 16,
    q: 17,
    r: 18,
    s: 19,
    t: 20,
    u: 21,
    v: 22,
    w: 23,
    x: 24,
    y: 25,
    z: 26
  }

  let word = words[i];
  let wordCount = 0;

  //loop through all words in the string

  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

    let word = words[i];

    //loop through all characters in each word

    for (let j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {

      let value = alphabetScore[j];

      wordCount += alphabetScore[value];

    }
  }
  return wordCount;
}

console.log(high("man i need a taxi up to ubud"));
```

And this is returning an error saying

> i is not defined

in `let word = words[i]` - how else would I define a word, then?

If it's possible to solve this Kata with my existing logic (using for-loops), please do so.

**EDIT**: Changed `wordCount = alphabetScore.value++;` to `wordCount += alphabetScore[value];`

**EDIT 2**: This is now returning `NaN`

**EDIT 3**: Latest attempt:

```
function myScore(input) {
    let key = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j",
    "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v",
    "w", "x", "y", "z"
    ];
    let bestWord = "";
    let bestScore = 0;
    let words = input.split(" ");
    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      let score = 0;
      let word = words[i];
      for (let j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
        let char = word[j];
        score += (key.indexOf(char) + 1);
      }
      if (score > bestScore) {
        bestScore = score;
        bestWord = word;
      }
    }
    return bestWord;
  }
```

> ReferenceError: high is not defined
>       at Test.describe._

Comment: Why don't you just keep the word with the highest score?

Comment: Okay - I don't know how to isolate the word with the highest score, though.

Comment: You need to put your `let word = words[i];` _inside_ your for-loop where `i` is defined.

Comment: @StephenP defined `word` within the first for-loop, defined `value` within the second for-loop. The function is now returning `NaN`.

Comment: first change `if (score > bestScore) {
            bestScore = score;
            word = bestWord;
        }` to `if (score > bestScore) {
            bestScore = score;
            bestWord = word;
        }`

Comment: @Mansoor edited, still returns undefined, does not work in Codewars.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56865348/3950069 - check my answer @HappyHands31

Comment: @Mansoor it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ran successfully on codewars

```js
let key = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j",
  "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v",
  "w", "x", "y", "z"
];

function wordScore(word) {
  let score = 0;
  for (let j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
    let char = word[j];
    score += (key.indexOf(char) + 1);
  }
  return score;
}

function high(x) {
  let bestWord = "";
  let bestScore = 0;
  words = x.split(" ");
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    let word = words[i];
    let score = wordScore(word);
    if (score > bestScore) {
      bestScore = score;
      bestWord = word;
    }
  }
  return bestWord;
}

console.log(high("man i need a taxi up to ubud"));
```

Comment: works in the console but not on [Codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/57eb8fcdf670e99d9b000272/train/javascript), for some reason

Comment: Yep! So what did you change? You've declared arguments `word` and `x`? Also would you mind posting the solution before you refactored, as well?

Comment: changed `let bestWord;` to `let bestWord = "";` so that undefined is not returned if input is a blank string

Comment: So, if you take a look at my most recent edit ("latest attempt" above) - what about that code is incorrect compared to what you just did? I see the main difference being that you created a helper function for each word?

Answer (score 2):

`NaN` means "not a number."  It's usually a sign that you've tried to do arithmetic on a null or something at some point.

In this instance, your `alphabetScore` is a hashmap of letters - but you're looking for *numeric* keys `let value = alphabetScore[j];`: that will return `undefined` and `undefined + 0 == NaN`.  Instead you need to say `let value = alphabetScore[word[j]]` - get the *letter* of the word, not the index.

To do as Jonas suggested, make two new variables where your first `let word = words[i]` is - and get rid of that - `let highScore = 0; let highScoreWord = "";` to hold the highest one you find.  Move the `let wordCount = 0;` inside the loop as well. Now, for each word, you'll get the word, and reset the count.

Finally, after the inner loop, say, `if (wordCount > highScore) { highScore = wordCount; highScoreWord = word; }`.  So if it's higher than your current highest, save it; otherwise just ignore it.

Then `return highScoreWord` and you should be golden!